# Error 500: nested exception is: psdi.util.MXSystemException: BMXAA4160E - A major exception has occurred

Tags: maximo

Uploading job plans into MAXIMO 7.6 using mxloader sheet; the next jonb plan does not go in because of ERROR 500  stating that 'BMXAA4160E - A major exception has occurred' comes up.

I have queried successful uploads from the DEMO and then used to format for mine.

I expect that all the distinct job plans upload at one run of the MXloader. This is the error message that I received

```
Error 500: nested exception is: psdi.util.MXSystemException:     
BMXAA4160E - A major exception has occurred. Check the system log to 
see if there are any companion errors logged. Report this error to your 
system administrator.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Oluwatomisin - Please mind to share any peace of information which you think can help solving this issue. What code have you written to solve it, what references were you targeted to check this issue.

Comment: there were no codes written, rather it is an upload into MAXIMO from mxloader sheet. the upload keeps bringing the error mentioned above when loading job plans.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Were there other errors just before or just after this one? Have you tried creating a Job Plan manually (as yourself in the Job Plans application)?